# How can you rename deployed meteor app from terminal?

Tags: meteor, web-deployment

After you deploy a meteor app - let's say foo.meteor.com - can you rename the app URL?

Answer (score 6):

[Doesn't look like it](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteordeploy), but you could always just delete it and deploy a new one:

```
meteor deploy --delete YOUR_APP
meteor deploy YOUR_NEW_APP
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Meteor command line](http://docs.meteor.com/#commandline) doesn't have any command for renaming your deployed application.

But you can just deploy your application with a new name instead of the old one as:

```
meteor deploy new_app_name.meteor.com
```